# To see javascript function names in event list on VS.NET 2008 IDE

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008

I wonder that is there any way to see all function names in Event combo-box on Visual Studio 2008 IDE?

[image: like CS file method names]

Answer (score 0):

No, and it would not make sense for the IDE to do this because **functions are not events**.  Rather, a function can be associated as a handler for an event, but the function itself is not the event.  You might have many functions that are not associated as a handler for any event, so it would not make sense to show these functions in a dropdown that lists events that are available for an object.

Also, the IDE will show the events in relation to some object.  For example, if you were to choose the **window** object in the Client Object and Events dropdown, then the Events combo box would show the events that are available for that object and for which you may associate a handler.

[image]

In this example, if you select an event in the Events combo box that has no associated handlers, Visual Studio will create a function automatically, but what may not be as apparent is that it *also* modifies the body tag and associates the function as a handler for the event.

Also see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp for specifics on JavaScript events.